# Apache is crashing when executing my PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, apache, recursion

I currently have around 34k pins/auths generated in my database, and when I run this it just says `This webpage is not available` and says that apache crashed. I'm not sure what's causing it to crash because it generated 34k so far without problems. If I could get pointers or anything on what's causing my script to crash that would be great. Thanks. Also I'm running this on a local wamp server. So it gave me an apache crash popup, but I can't seem to get it to show again.

EDIT Here's the crash pop up info:

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_httpd.exe_7bb4b47e7db260ba266dfdf76b7ba24f8a5e099_cab_175bb644\WERB55A.tmp.appcompat.txt
      C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_httpd.exe_7bb4b47e7db260ba266dfdf76b7ba24f8a5e099_cab_175bb644\WERB56A.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
      C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_httpd.exe_7bb4b47e7db260ba266dfdf76b7ba24f8a5e099_cab_175bb644\WERB5E9.tmp.mdmp`

error log:

`[Sat Apr 12 19:17:01.362346 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3124:tid 412] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Sat Apr 12 19:17:01.363346 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3124:tid 412] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 940
[Sat Apr 12 19:17:01.599360 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 940:tid 308] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sat Apr 12 19:17:04.302514 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3124:tid 412] AH00428: Parent: child process 940 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Sat Apr 12 19:17:04.389519 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3124:tid 412] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Apr 12 19:17:04.389519 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3124:tid 412] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Sat Apr 12 19:17:04.389519 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3124:tid 412] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Sat Apr 12 19:17:04.391519 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3124:tid 412] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2996
[Sat Apr 12 19:17:04.647534 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2996:tid 308] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.`

code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 1000000); //this is to fix the recursion?
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000000); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
    ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    //Enter your database connection details here.
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db_name = 'pins'; 
    $db_username = 'root';
    $db_password = ''; 
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    try
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        exit('Error Connecting To DataBase');
    }
    $starttime = microtime(true);
    class lists
    {
        public $pdo;
        function __construct($pdo)
        {
            $this->pdo = $pdo;
        }
        function duplicateCode($code)
        {
            $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM pins WHERE pins_pin = ?");
            $query->bindValue(1, $code);
            $query->execute();
            return $query->fetch();
        }
        function generateCode()
        {
            $code = "AA" . substr(str_shuffle('0123456789'), 0, 8);
            if($this->duplicateCode($code))
            {
                return $this->generateCode();
            }
            else
            {
                return $code;
            }
        }   
        function generatePin($code)
        {
            $query = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO pins (pins_pin) VALUES (?)");
            $query->bindValue(1, $code);
            $query->execute();
            return;
        }
    }
    function post_to_url($url, $data) {
        $fields = '';
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        }
        rtrim($fields, '&');

        $post = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($post);

        curl_close($post);
        return $result;
    }
    $list = new lists($pdo);
    for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
    {
        $code = $list->generateCode();
        $pin = $list->generatePin($code);
    }
    $endtime = microtime(true);
    $duration = $endtime - $starttime; //calculates total time taken
    echo $duration;
?>
```

Comment: Check your error log (`tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` if you're *nix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that you're exceeding an internal recursion limit by calling `lists::generateCode()` repeatedly.

An easy fix for this will be to eliminate the recursion:

```
function generateCode()
{
    do {
        $code = "AA" . substr(str_shuffle('0123456789'), 0, 8);
    } while ($this->duplicateCode($code));
    return $code;
}
```

However, there's a more fundamental issue at hand here. Your code is generating codes which begin with two As, then contain 6 digits, all of which must be different. There are only [10! ÷ (10 - 6)!](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10p6) = 151,200 possible codes which fit this pattern - once you have generated all of them, no more will be available, and even this corrected code will loop endlessly. (Additionally, if `str_shuffle()` does not visit all of the possible permutations — which is entirely possible — the set of possible outputs will be even smaller than this.)

Unless you have a hard requirement that all six digits be different, I would strongly recommend that you instead use any sequence of six digits, *e.g.*:

```
  $code = sprintf("AA%06d", rand(0, 999999));
```

Comment: there needs to be 8 digits. so for example AA00000000 which should be 1 million possible codes.